# Disable hover on image depending on link url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress gallery created with Envira Gallery plugin. I need to disable hover for those images that didn't link to any page and have "#" as url.
Is there a way to disable any hover effect for the images with "#" url?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `img[href="#"]` as a selector.

Comment: I have to assign a class to modify hover only to the images that have "#" as url. How can I use your solution?

Comment: bhansa made an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a **jquery** solution instead.

You can override your css style using jquery [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method. You can specify css for `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

Use `a[href*="#"] > img` as selector, to target all links which has `href="#"` to images.

```js
$('a[href*="#"] > img').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
  },

  function() {
    $(this).css('background', '');
  }
);
```

```css
a:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#"><img src="#" alt="image" /></a>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com"><img src="" alt="ref image" /></a>

<a href="#"> Only link withuout image</a>
```

Comment: sorry but I'm unskilled in javascript. Can i use "img[href*="#"]" instead of "img[src*="#"] "?

Comment: img have src attribute, links have href. so use src.

Comment: but my img cames from a gallery created with envira gallery plugin so the src attribute is not # but the source of the img.

Comment: @Luca sorry I misjudged the question, I have updated the solution. Please check. If this solves the problem please think about accepting or upvoting. Thanks.